# AttributeError: module 'flask' has no attribute 'route'

Tags: python, flask

```
import flask 
import sentimentanalyzer
app: object = flask


@app.route("/")
def default() :
    return "Hello world>>!!"``

@app.route("/predictsentiment/<query>",method=['GET'])
def predict(query):
    sentiment = sentimentanalyzer.returnSentiment(query)
    return flask.jsonify(sentiment)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: What did you intend by `app: object = flask` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the flask class from the flask module. Check how to make minimal application [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application)

```
import flask 
import sentimentanalyzer
app: flask.Flask = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def default() :
    return "Hello world>>!!"

@app.route("/predictsentiment/<query>")
def predict(query):
    sentiment = sentimentanalyzer.returnSentiment(query)
    return flask.jsonify(sentiment)

if _name_== "  main  ":
    app.run()
```

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method' getting this error now

Comment: @umeshhb Use methods instead of method

Comment: charchit that gave me intern server error

Comment: Use app.run(debug= True) for correct error or see it in console.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: @umeshhb if it is only GET route, then `@app.route` will by default register for GET method. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Flask class from flask module.

```
from flask import Flask
import sentimentanalyzer

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def default() :
    return "Hello world>>!!"

@app.route("/predictsentiment/<query>",methods=['GET'])
def predict(query):
    sentiment = sentimentanalyzer.returnSentiment(query)
    return flask.jsonify(sentiment)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'

Comment: on line `@app.route("/predictsentiment/<query>",methods=['GET'])` you wrote **method** instead **methods**, pay also attention to **/predictsentiment/<query>** and `def predict(qurey):` (**qurey**)

Comment: after all corrections i got this Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: The http get call on route "/" returns 200 and print "Hello Wolrd"? If so, the error is inside the method `sentimentanalyzer.returnSentiment(query)`, I suggest you open another question as this is about the flask error.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference the Quickstart docs here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

You need to create an object from the Flask class to get started.

And methods needs to be plural. (ref: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#http-methods)

Not relevant tot the question the default route has invalid syntax with the double backticks resulting in:

```
  File "/home/tom/tmp/test.py", line 8
    return "Hello world>>!!"``
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Regards,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I see you have not found a solution yet.

```
from flask import Flask
import sentimentanalyzer

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def default() :
    return "Hello world>>!!"

@app.route("/predictsentiment/<query>",methods=['GET'])
def predict(query):
    sentiment = sentimentanalyzer.returnSentiment(query)
    return flask.jsonify(sentiment)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Though the above code is correct, your error may be the initialization or the structure of the app. Please post the structure.
**init**.py needs to be put in a directory and the directory is called.
Try renaming your **init**.py to app.py, should solve the error.